Essbase Rest API MDX — need ROWS axis
I have a problem with MDX queries.
Previosly I used SOAP web services and used MDX with tuples.
I need a data for cells that can be aquired by a query like this:
SELECT
{ 
    ([Market].[East],[Product].[Audio],[Year].[Qtr1]),
    ([Market].[West],[Product].[Audio],[Year].[Qtr2]),
    ([Market].[West],[Product].[Visual],[Year].[Qtr3]) 
} 
ON COLUMNS

But when I use Rest API call /applications/{application}/databases/{database}/mdx, it returns empty data as it requires the ROWS axis.
I can use ROWS if all cells have a common tuple member.
E.g.
SELECT
{ 
    ([Market].[East],[Product].[Audio],[Year].[Qtr1]),
    ([Market].[West],[Product].[Audio],[Year].[Qtr2]),
    ([Market].[West],[Product].[Audio],[Year].[Qtr3]) 
} 
ON COLUMNS

can be transformed to
SELECT
{ 
    ([Market].[East],[Year].[Qtr1]),
    ([Market].[West],[Year].[Qtr2]),
    ([Market].[West],[Year].[Qtr3]) 
} 
ON COLUMNS
{ ([Product].[Audio]) } ON ROWS

But I need solution in the common case where all cells may have no common members.
Maybe it's possible to add some «fictional» axis? Something like SELECT 'constant' FROM demo; in SQL.
